# After the privacy issue changes, is it possible to extract user details from facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-python-business-sdk

I am trying to build a Python flask application to extract user details (like full-name, other publicly visible profile details like favourite-athletes, favourite-movies, liked content, etc.). I would further like to perform persona analytics based on this data.

After the changes in Facebook API resulting form privacy issues it had to face, is it still possible to extract these details for OTHER users (I know I can get my own, which is not useful to me). Please help, thanks in advance!

This page- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes/ does mention the changes, however changes to User details are not explicitly called out.

Answer (score 0):

Data of other users is not allowed and not possible. Only data of users who specifically authorized your App is available. Without authorization, you cannot even get a User ID.

It does not matter if data is public on facebook.com, you still need authorization to use it.

Comment: Hello @luschn, even on public contents ?

Comment: Yes, even on that. Public via UI does not mean publicly available via API, without the users explicit consent in form of granting your app permission.

Comment: what 04FS said, i added it to my answer